# jquery not working for setting a sibling td text within a table

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following table data:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" data-usage="payment" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" data-usage="payment" /></td>
  <td data-usage="amount"></td>
</tr>
```

Then I was trying to make it so when the user leaves a textbox with data-usage="payment" the td with data-usage="amount" has its text set to "info". I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("input[data-usage='payment']").blur(function () {

            $(this).closest("td[data-usage='amount']").text("info");
        });

    });
</script>
```

I don't understand why but this doesn't even work. The event is fired and it seems to find the td but the text isn't even set.

Can anyone tell me why? Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` only searches in the parents of the element, you're looking for the closest TR and then a TD with the data attribute:

```
$("input[data-usage='payment']").blur(function () {
     $(this).closest("tr").find("td[data-usage='amount']").text("info");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[data-usage='amount']` td is a not a parent of the target input element, it is in fact a sibling of the `td` that contains the target input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[data-usage='payment']").blur(function () {
        $(this).closest("td").siblings("[data-usage='amount']").text("info");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PER7W/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete example :

```
    $("input[data-usage='payment']").blur(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td[data-usage='amount']").text("info");
    });
```

here is example : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/48L73/)